# KDB/Q : What is Vector operation?

Tags: kdb

I am learning KDB+ and Q programming and read about the following statement -
 "select performs vector operations on column lists". What does **Vector operation** mean here? Could somebody please explain with an example? Also, How its faster than standard SQL?

Answer (score 5):

A vector operation is an operation that takes one or more vectors and produces another vector.  For example `+` in q is a vector operation:

```
q)a:1 2 3
q)b:10 20 30
q)a + b
11 22 33
```

If `a` and `b` are columns in a table, you can perform vector operations on them in a `select` statement.  Continuing with the previous example, let's put `a` and `b` vectors in a table as columns:

```
q)([]a;b)
a b
----
1 10
2 20
3 30
```

Now,

```
q)select c:a + b from ([]a;b)
c
--
11
22
33
```

The select statement performed the same `a+b` vector addition, but took input and returned output as table columns.

> How its faster than standard SQL?

"Standard" SQL implementations typically store data row by row.  In a table with many columns the first element of a column and its second element can be separated in memory by the data from other columns.  Modern computers operate most efficiently when the data is stored contiguously.  In kdb+, this is achieved by storing tables column by column.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Alexander.

Answer (score 0):

A [vector](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/elements/#vectors) is a list of atoms of the same type. Some examples:

```
2 3 4 5                   / int
"A fine, clear day"       / char 
`ibm`goog`aapl`ibm`msft   / symbol
2017.01 2017.02 2017.03m  / month
```

Kdb+ stores and handles vectors very efficiently. Q [operators](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/elements/#operators) – not just `+-*%` but e.g. `mcount`, `ratios`, `prds` – are optimised for vectors.

These operators can be even more efficient when vectors have [*attributes*](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/elements/#attributes), such as `u` (no repeated items) and `s` (items are in ascending order).

When table columns are vectors, those same efficiencies are available. These efficiencies are not available to standard SQL, which views tables as unordered sets of rows.

Being column-oriented, kdb+ can [*splay*](http://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/splayed-tables/) large tables, storing each column as a separate file, which reduces file I/O when selecting from large tables.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence means when you refer to a specific column of a table with a column label, it is resolved into the whole column list, rather than each element of it, and any operations on it shall be understood as list operations.

```
q)show t: flip `a`b!(til 3;10*til 3)
a b 
----
0 0 
1 10
2 20
q)select x: count a, y: type b from t
x y
---
3 7
q)type t[`b]
7h
q)type first t[`b]
-7h
```

`count a` in the above q-sql is equivalent to `` count t[`a] `` which is `count 0 1 2` = 3. The same goes to `type b`; the positive return value 7 means `b` is a list rather than an atom: http://code.kx.com/q/ref/datatypes/#primitive-datatypes